# Help with definition of amenable groups.

Tags: group-theory, amenability

I am reading some lecture notes that have the following definition of a left invariant mean on a group:

$G$ is called amenable if there exists a bounded linear functional $m:L^{\infty}(G) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that:

$1)$ $m(f)\geq0$ for all $f\geq 0$

$2)$ $m(1_{G})=1$

$3)$ $m$ is left-invariant $(m(f)=m(\lambda_{g}f)$ for all $f\in L^{\infty}(G)$ and $g \in G$)

What I don't understand is, if $m$ is a function to $\mathbb{C}$ then what does $m(f)\geq 0$ mean? Or should $m$ actually be a function onto $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: It means $m(f)$ is a non-negative real number in $\mathbb{C}$ for all non-negative real valued function $f$.

Comment: Maybe you should write $L^\infty(G,\mathbf{C})$, since $L^\infty(G)$ could also mean its subspace of real-valued functions. As said in the previous comment, sometimes the notation $x\ge 0$ for $x\in\mathbf{C}$ is used to mean that $x\in\mathbf{R}$ and $x\ge 0$ in the usual sense, and by extension $f\ge 0$ means that $f(g)\ge 0$ for a.e. $g\in G$.

Comment: It should be a functional to reals, $m$ is a finitely additive probability measure and that is always real.